# i want to find sum of array first and last element and 2nd and 2nd last element and 3rd and 3rd last element and so on

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, sum

here remember array size and values is defined by user by the help of scanner class and i am using java
task is to find sum of first and last element and 2nd and 2nd last and so on 
i already try research but failed 
thanks in advance

```
int sum = 0; 
int f = 0;
System.out.println("Your Array is even");
System.out.println("Kinldy enter Your Values of Array");
for(int i = 0 ; i<array.length ; i++) 
{  
    array[i] = s.nextInt();
    for(int j = 0 ; j< array.length-i-1 ; j++)
    {
        sum = j + array.length+1 ;
    }
}    
System.out.println("Your Sum " + sum);
```

Comment: You are not adding the array values, but the index here: `sum = j + array.length+1 ;`.

Comment: B001 what will be the value of sum man

Comment: i added your code and i got answer of 1 2 3 4 array size 4 answer is Your Sum -2147483643

Comment: can u send me code man ??

Answer (score 3):

You could just loop over your array and use the index to find the corresponding numbers from both sides.

The first element can be found by simply doing: `array[i]`.

The corresponding element from the other side can be found by: `array[array.length - 1 - i]`.

The complete code could be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = {1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 8};
    
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) 
    {  
        int firstNumber = array[i];
        int secondNumber = array[array.length - 1 - i];
        
        int sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        System.out.println(firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + " = " + sum);
    }    
}
```

Output:

> 1 + 8 = 9
>
> 3 + 1 = 4
>
> 6 + 4 = 10

I made the assumption that you only want to do this for half of the array. That's why the `for` loop is only executed as long as `i<array.length / 2`. This solution assumes that the length of your array is always an even number. If your array has an uneven length, the middle element will not be considered.

In case you do want to do this for the complete array, all you have to do is remove the `/ 2` from the `for` loop statement. The output will be:

> 1 + 8 = 9
>
> 3 + 1 = 4
>
> 6 + 4 = 10
>
> 4 + 6 = 10
>
> 1 + 3 = 4
>
> 8 + 1 = 9

Comment: Very nice solution.. but just be aware that if the number of elements is even, the middle element will not be considered.. e.g. {1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 8, 9}; and 4 would be the middle element